# How to start Fragment within custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

i am trying to start a new fragment within the custom ArrayAdapter.
when i using the function getFragmentManager() i get:

"`cannot resolve method getFragmentManger method"`

i would like that when i click on item, new Fragment from type "CreateEventFragmentController" will be created.

this is the code of the custom ArrayAdapter:

```
    package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.DBcontroller;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.Fragments.CreateEventFragmentController;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.InterfacesAndConstants.AsyncResponse;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.InterfacesAndConstants.Constants;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.R;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    /**
     * this class define tha adapter of the event management and handling
     * all the event delete requests.
     * Created by matant on 11/4/2015.
     */
    public class ManageEventArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ManageEventListRow> implements AsyncResponse {
        Context context;
        List<ManageEventListRow> mngEvents;
        private DBcontroller dbController;
        private ManageEventListRow rowEvent;
        private ProgressDialog progress;

        public ManageEventArrayAdapter(Context ctx,int resourceId, List<ManageEventListRow> items){
            super(ctx, resourceId, items);
            this.context = ctx;
            this.mngEvents = items;
        }
        /*private view holder class*/
        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView imageViewType;
            TextView txtSport;
            TextView txtDate;
            TextView txtLoc;
            TextView txtTime;
            TextView txtParticipants;
            ImageButton imgDelete;
        }
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            //final  View vi;

            final ManageEventListRow rowItem = getItem(position);
            rowEvent = rowItem;

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.manage_event_listview_event, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtSport =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
                holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDateValue);
                holder.txtLoc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLocationval);
                holder.txtTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewtimeval);
                holder.txtParticipants = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewparticipantsVal);
                holder.imgDelete = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDeleteEvent);
                holder.imageViewType = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSporttype);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.txtSport.setText(rowItem.getSportType());
            holder.txtDate.setText(rowItem.getDate());
            holder.txtLoc.setText(rowItem.getEventLocation());
            holder.txtTime.setText(rowItem.getEtime());
            holder.txtParticipants.setText(rowItem.getParticipants());
            holder.imageViewType.setImageResource(rowItem.getSportImage());

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  Fragment fragment = new CreateEventFragmentController();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("Tag", "edit_event");
                    args.putString("json", rowItem.getEventRecord().toString());

                }
            });

            holder.imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("Event Id is:", rowItem.getEventId());
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                            .setTitle("Delete Event")
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this event?")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    sendDataToDBController();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                            .setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon)
                            .show();

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }



        public void setData(List<ManageEventListRow> list){
            this.mngEvents = list;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleResponse(String resStr) {
            progress.dismiss();
            Log.d("Delete Event handleResponse", resStr);
            if (resStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(resStr);
                    String flg = jsonObj.getString(Constants.TAG_FLG);
                    switch (flg){
                        case Constants.TAG_REQUEST_FAILED:
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        case Constants.TAG_REQUEST_SUCCEED:
                        {
                            mngEvents.remove(rowEvent);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void sendDataToDBController() {
            String id = rowEvent.getEventId();
            Log.d("event id to delete:",id);
            BasicNameValuePair tagreq = new BasicNameValuePair(Constants.TAG_REQUEST, "delete_event");
            BasicNameValuePair eventparam = new BasicNameValuePair("event_id", id);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairList.add(tagreq);
            nameValuePairList.add(eventparam);
            dbController = new DBcontroller(getContext(),this);
            dbController.execute(nameValuePairList);

        }

        @Override
        public void preProcess() {
            this.progress = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Delete Event!",
                    "Deleting event...", true);

        }
    }
```

how can i using the Bundle object using your answer? – user5494424 2 mins ago   edit

for this line 
"`((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_fra‌​me, new CreateEventFragmentController("edit_text",rowItem.getEventRecord().toString())).commit();"`

i got this error:

```
wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.Fragments.CreateEventFragmentContr‌​oller', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' less...
```

Comment: Don't create Fragments in Adapters; provide a Callback to the Activity or create an Adapter-like Factory instead.

Comment: because `getFragmentManger` is not a method of `ArrayAdapter` ... you can bubble up the event to the Activity or at least parent fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace a fragment without params  ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new Fragment()).commit();

If you want to put a Bundle as a param in it then the instantiated Fragment should have a constructor that can accept Bundle object

```
Bundle bun = new Bundle()
bun.putInt()
bun.putBoolean()
```

Then pass the bun

Comment: in addition i need to pass to the new fragment some parameters how should i do that regarding your post?

Comment: i also get an error on the "R.id.container: cannot resolve"

Comment: In your case `((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,new Fragment()).commit();`

Comment: ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new CreateEventFragmentController(Object param1,Object param2,...)).commit();

Comment: R.id.container is the View that you are going to replace.

Comment: Which is in the xml file that your activity uses in the setContentView() in the onCreate() method

Comment: i don't using the constructor to pass parameters cant i do it with Bundle object?

Comment: You can your fragment should accept a Bundle object though

Comment: how can i using the Bundle object using your answer?

Comment: for this line "((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,
                        new CreateEventFragmentController("edit_text", rowItem.getEventRecord().toString())).commit();" i got this error: rong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers.Fragments.CreateEventFragmentController', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' less...

Comment: This answer came up in the review queue as a low-quality answer, because it is code-only and very short. Looking at the comments, I think it may be incomplete. Instead of doing all these updates in comments, can you please edit your answer to make it a more complete answer? Keep in mind that comments may be removed at some point by SO, so it's better to have the complete solution (not just code, also with explanation) in the answer itself.